# Django: how to set content-type header to text/xml within a class-based view?

Tags: django, http-headers, mime-types, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to do it this way, but it doesn't work.

```
class MyView(View):

    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles responding to requests for the OPTIONS HTTP verb.
        """
        response = http.HttpResponse()
        if self.kwargs.has_key('xml'):
            response['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        return response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the key point is `render_to_response` in `django.views.generic.base` , whose code is this:

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    """
    Returns a response, using the `response_class` for this
    view, with a template rendered with the given context.

    If any keyword arguments are provided, they will be
    passed to the constructor of the response class.
    """
    response_kwargs.setdefault('content_type', self.content_type)   # key
    return self.response_class(
        request=self.request,
        template=self.get_template_names(),
        context=context,
        **response_kwargs
    )
```

As for your case, May be you need this code:

```
class MyView(ListView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()

        if self.kwargs.has_key('xml'):
            return self.render_to_response(context, content_type="text/xml; charset=utf-8")
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It can also be used in a such way, as I have figured out:

`class MyView(TemplateView):

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response = super(HelpGivenView,self).render_to_response(
        context, **response_kwargs)
        if self.kwargs.has_key('xml'):
            response['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        return response`

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to write additional code. Use [TemplateResponseMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin) and set **content_type** attribute to whatever you need:

```
class MyView(TemplateResponseMixin):
    content_type='application/xml'
    ...
```

Comment: best answer. no method overriding, just adding an attribute to your view. wont get it cheaper!

Answer (score 1):

I made a middleware class based off of [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers) so I could allow iframe-ing of part of my django app. I keep a middleware.py in my main project directory and save a couple random middleware classes I have made there, like this one here and a [ForceResponse Exception](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2541/) for example.

```
import re
from django import http
from django.conf import settings

class XFrameAllowMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        """
        If CORS preflight header, then create an
        empty body response (200 OK) and return it

        Django won't bother calling any other request
        view/exception middleware along with the requested view;
        it will call any response middlewares
        """
        if (self.is_enabled(request) and
                request.method == 'OPTIONS' and
                "HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD" in request.META):
            response = http.HttpResponse()
            return response
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if self.is_enabled(request):
            response['X-Frame-Options'] = 'ALLOWALL'
        return response

    def is_enabled(self, request):
        return re.match(settings.XFRAME_URLS_REGEX, request.path)
```

Add it to your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and configure the regex in your settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'your_django_app.middleware.XFrameAllowMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)

XFRAME_URLS_REGEX = r'^/iframe_this_url/.*$'
```

from the django-cors-headers read.me:

> CORS_URLS_REGEX: specify a URL regex for which to enable the sending of CORS headers; Useful when you only want to enable CORS for specific URLs, e. g. for a REST API under /api/.
>   Example:

```
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'^/api/.*$'
```

> Default:

```
CORS_URLS_REGEX = '^.*$'
```