# How to return XML to ajax in django?

Tags: javascript, java, python, django, mxgraph

I want to return XML data back to the client that can be displayed as a graph in mxGraph.

My main goal is to save the mxGraph to the server, so whenever a user accesses the same page, the graph displayed is the same graph where the user left it. The xml data is getting saved in the server but is not getting returned as an xml back to the client.

Currently, I tried to return it as JSON, thinking it would be okay to use the value as XML. However, there are "/n" being returned with it, so it doesn't parse properly.

**views.py**

```
def saveData(request, user):
if request.method == "POST":
#Get user profile
    member = Member.objects.get(username=user)
#Get XML data once user presses save
#xmlData = request.POST['xml']
    member.data = request.POST['xml']
    member.save()
    print(member.data)
    response = JsonResponse([
        member.data
    ], safe = False);
    #return render(request, 'fastcookapp/index.html', {"xmlData": member.data})
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")


return HttpResponse('POST is not used')
```

**ajax**

```
var button = mxUtils.button('Save', function()
            {

                var encoder = new mxCodec();
                var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
                var xml = mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node); 
                var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/saveData/",
                    data: { "xml": xml},
                    headers:{
                        "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log("data" + data[0])

                        //functions in mxgraph to decode the xml back to a graph
                        var xmlDoc = mxUtils.parseXml(data[0]);
                        var node = xmlDoc.documentElement;
                        //console.log("node " + node)
                        var dec = new mxCodec(node.ownerDocument);
                        //console.log("dec " + dec)
                        //console.log("graph model " + graph.getModel())
                        dec.decode(node, graph.getModel());

                    }
                });

                //console.log(xml);
                //mxUtils.popup(mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node), true);
            });
```

**models.py**

```
class Member(User):
data = models.TextField(null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856040/django-how-to-set-content-type-header-to-text-xml-within-a-class-based-view

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you:

You should not JsonResponse yet, because the data you are working on is XML, not JSON.

Do this way:

1 - At the top of the **views.py**

```
import xmltodict
```

2 - Inside of your method (def) code like this:

```
real_response = response.content

response_as_dict = xmltodict.parse(real_response)

return JsonResponse(response_as_dict)
```

3 - In your ajax success callback you should work on the data:

For example :

```
success: function(data) {

         var textBox = document.getElementById('textBox');

          textBox.innerText = data.parentNode.node;

      }
```

I am sure it will work for you!

During the process, debug and see what needs to be replaced on "parentNode" and "node". It was just an example.